# Printing a diamond of numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, formatting

If you input the number 3 from the keyboard, the program will show this:

```
      0
    0 1 0
  0 1 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 2 1 0
  0 1 2 1 0
    0 1 0
      0
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned i,k=0,n;
    cout<<"n= "; cin>>n;

    while(k<=n)
        {

            for (i=0;i<=k;i++)
                cout<<i;
            for (i=k;i>0;i--)
                cout<<i-1;
            cout<<endl;
            k++;
        }

    k=n;

    while (k)
        {
            k--;
            for (i=0;i<=k;i++)
                cout<<i;
            for (i=k;i>0;i--)
                cout<<i-1;
            cout<<endl;

        }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a better/easier/clever way to do this?
2. How to deal with spaces? How to show them? (because my code is working but it doesn't show spaces to make this diamond look)

Answer (score 10):

- [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is not preferred, although not that bad for small programs.
- Each variable should be declared/initialized on separate lines.  This improves readability and also makes it easier to add any necessary comments.

  ```
  unsigned i;
  unsigned k = 0;
  unsigned n;
  ```

  Same with this:

  ```
  cout << "n= ";
  cin >> n;
  ```
- Prefer `"\n"` to [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) here (the latter flushes the buffer, which takes longer).  It's still okay to use the latter where *both* flushing and newlining are needed.
- Always use descriptive names for variables.  Single-characters are best for loop counters (such as `i`).  This will vastly improve readability as you won't need comments to describe them.
- It looks like you could use recursion instead of all these loops.  It may take longer (if you input a large number), but it should at least simplify the logic.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Professors from high school where I learn are a little overwhelmed by these practices. I used to work in their way unfortunately. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user2105306: Heck, my *college professors* still use `using namespace std` just because it's used in the books...

Comment: Out of interest: why is `using namespace std` frowned upon?

Comment: @KentBoogaart: That link explains most of it.  Personally, I prefer to keep the STL separate from other code, since there's a lot of info in that namespace.  Beyond that, it looks like many just dislike `using namespace X` in general.  Although it's okay to have it local, I'm used to not using it at all.  I was first told about this in my [first question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/22805/please-critique-my-c-deck-class) here.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your link. I find the argument unconvincing, especially for `std`. It's like saying don't do `using System;` in .NET and instead write `System.Bla` or `global::System.Bla` everywhere. If I later update a dependency that also includes, say, a `Tuple<T>` type, then I can disambiguate as necessary at that point.

Comment: The relation between *use recursion* and *don't use `std::endl`* seems a bit strange to me ;) ...I'd say in this case, performance isn't such an important issue.

Comment: @Wolf: True, but I was primarily going after some minor aspects since I can't assess the algorithm too well (mainly why I just *mentioned* recursion without giving a relevant example).

Answer (score 8):

Spacing could be accomplished using [`std::setw()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/).

The diamond-generating code should at least be in its own function — I suggest a function like `void diamond(std::ostream &out, int size)`.  Keep `main()` simple: just read the size and call `diamond(std::cout, n)`.  Better yet, you could define a `Diamond` class — see my [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/31754/9357) to a similar question.

From the linked example, also pick up some ideas about the loop structure and descriptive variable naming.  Since this is an exercise and you have quite a bit of work ahead of you, I'll refrain from posting too many details here.